# facebook sharing in Angular Application

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook, angular6, angular5

- I am working on an Angular Web Application,
- I am trying to share my content on facebook
- When I am trying to share facebook popup opens and I am getting
  message ***href should represent a valid URL***
- I want to share content like

> 'Use Referral code xyzUvK    to join the newest fantasy sports
>   platform http://example.com . Earn extra points along with lots of
>   exciting prizes. Don’t delay, join the match today! url',

**code**

**html**

```
 <a href="#" (click)="fb($event)"><img src="assets/imgs/fb.svg"/></a>
```

**ts**

```
fb(e) {
    let url = 'www.google.com';
    e.preventDefault();
    var facebookWindow = window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+ 'Use Referral code ->' + this.userData.referCode + '   to join the newest fantasy sports platform' +  url + '. Earn extra points along with lots of exciting prizes. Don’t delay, join the match today! url',
      'facebook-popup',
      'height=350,width=600'
    );
    if (facebookWindow.focus) {
      facebookWindow.focus();
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: I think FB won't allow us to share content like twitter does

Comment: @PardeepJain  then what is the sollution for this

Comment: @AnuragRanjan did you found any solution for this.?
i think my issue is beacause of iam testing in local machine?

Answer (score 1):

Please add meta tags in your **index.html** file

**Markup Example**

For example, here's how to mark up an article, news story or blog post with og:type="article" and several additional properties:

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

Comment: can you explain how to user this meta tag  , for facebook sharing , in the component

Answer (score 0):

Facebook only allows you to share URLs, not prefilled text like twitter. So your `u` parameter has to be a URL.

https://developers.facebook.com/policy#control

Comment: can you suggest me any solution for it